# I have to specify the highest and lowest values above the chart [HighCharts]

Tags: javascript, highcharts

[image]

I'm trying to specify those values but can't find any description in Highcharts documentation.

To give more context this is the chart that i'm working at the moment:

[[image]

I thinking about the possibility of doing this in html, outside of highcharts.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the required elements in HTML and update their content after the chart is created. For example:

```
const chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {...});
const yAxis = chart.yAxis[0];

document.getElementById('chart-data-min').innerHTML = yAxis.dataMin;
document.getElementById('chart-data-max').innerHTML = yAxis.dataMax;
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2d9mphby/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart